# Grid lines on top of stacked area plot

Tags: beamer, pgfplots

I created a stacked area graph and I would like to add grid lines. However, when I do it, the grid lines are on top of the stacked area plot. How can I make it the other way around (so the plot is on top of the grid lines)?

Here is a minimal working example (I know it's not the most efficient code, but I still need a lot to learn):

```
\documentclass[trans]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\usetikzlibrary{dateplot}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\usetheme{EastLansing}
\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{bg=pink,fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{bg=white,fg=magenta}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Liabilities of the Eurosystem}

\begin{center}
    \pgfplotsset{scaled y ticks=false}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
        \begin{axis}[
            every tick label/.append style={
                font=\scriptsize},
            every major grid/.append style={
                dashed},
            width=12cm,
            height=6cm,
            scale only axis,
            legend style={
                at={(0.05,0.95)},
                anchor={north west},
                line width=0.4pt},
            stack plots=y,
            area style,
            ymajorgrids=true,
            date coordinates in=x,
            date ZERO=2006-01-04,
            xmin=2006-01-04,
            xmax=2024-02-28,
            ylabel={\scriptsize \EUR billion},
            ymin=0,
            xticklabels={2006,2008,2010,2012,2014,2016,2018,2020,2022,2024},
            xtick={2006-01-04,2008-01-02,2010-01-06,2012-01-04,2014-01-01,2016-01-06,2018-01-03,2020-01-01,2022-01-05,2024-01-03},
            ymax=10000,
            ytick={2000,4000,6000,8000,10000},
            xticklabel={\year}
            ]
            
            \addplot [draw=cyan,fill=cyan] table[x=Date,y=OL] {ES_liabilities.txt} \closedcycle;
            \addplot [draw=teal,fill=teal] table[x=Date,y=BC] {ES_liabilities.txt} \closedcycle;
            \addplot [draw=orange,fill=orange] table[x=Date,y=CA] {ES_liabilities.txt} \closedcycle;
            \addplot [draw=purple,fill=purple] table[x=Date,y=DF] {ES_liabilities.txt} \closedcycle;
            \addplot [stack plots=false,line legend,draw=black,line width=3pt] table[x=Date,y=TL] {ES_liabilities.txt};
            
            \legend{{\tiny Other liabilities}, {\tiny Banknotes in circulation}, {\tiny Current accounts}, {\tiny Deposit facility}, 
                {\tiny Total liabilities}};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}  
{\scriptsize \textit{Source: ECB.}}



\transwipe
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The image it creates is this:
[image]

And another thing. The Total liabilites is a line, but in the legend it is very thick and I can't make it thinner. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @hperkristiansen You are right! I've done that.

Comment: Please make your code compilable.

Comment: I suggest to simplify your code a little (e.g. showing only two curves, moving to class standalone for this demo). I suggest to provide simplified data, i.e. just a few data points per file/table), so we can reproduce it.

Comment: Are you really creating transparencies to print out and use on an overhead projector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`area style` sets `axis on top`. - you can undo that by setting it to `false`. Or you can use `area cycle list` and `area legend` as you like.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
every tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
every major grid/.append style={dashed},
width=12cm, height=6cm, scale only axis,
stack plots=y,
area style, axis on top=false,
ymajorgrids=true,
date coordinates in=x,
xmin=2006-01-04, xmax=2024-02-28,
ymin=0, ymax=10000,
xtick={2006-01-04,2008-01-02,2010-01-06,2012-01-04,2014-01-01,2016-01-06,2018-01-03,2020-01-01,2022-01-05,2024-01-03},
xticklabels={2006,2008,2010,2012,2014,2016,2018,2020,2022,2024},
ytick={2000,4000,6000,8000,10000},
legend style={font=\tiny},
]
\addplot[cyan, fill=cyan] coordinates {(2006-01-04,1) (2024-01-04,3000)} \closedcycle;
\addplot[teal, fill=teal] coordinates {(2006-01-04,1) (2024-01-04,2000)} \closedcycle;
\addplot[orange, fill=orange] coordinates {(2006-01-04,1) (2024-01-04,2000)} \closedcycle;
\addplot[purple, fill=purple] coordinates {(2006-01-04,1) (2024-01-04,2000)} \closedcycle;
\legend{{Other liabilities}, {Banknotes in circulation}, {Current accounts}, {Deposit facility}, {Total liabilities}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with area plots]

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much! It's great that there are such simple options, but it's a shame I can't find them in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

For this demo I:

- used class `standalone`, which is often nicer to do during development
- mimicked your stacked data
- picked a handful of your options and commands
- left out all other oprions, e.g. related to dates etc
- showed simplified data

Many of your packages may not be needed here. E.g. `pgfplotstable` is useful when you want to convert your data file (=table) into tables useful in Latex; for plotting data you don't need it.

Not clear from your question, how you tried the grid. Anyway, the one shown obviously does it right.

Suggestions:

- start from this simple demo (i.e. copy the code into a new file)
- stepwise, transit more into what you showed, e.g.
- move from 1,2,3 to your date sequences (i.e. modify my table, add packages until it compiles)
- replace my table with your data files
- add more data files
- etc.

This approach is much like hiking in steep terrain or from top buildings: safety first, from safe to safe position (i.e. from compile to compile while approaching your goal).

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        stack plots=y,
        area style,
        grid=major,
        grid style={
            color=red, dashed},
        title=Demonstrating relevant commands,
    ]
        \addplot table{
            1   10
            2   100
            3   45
        } \closedcycle;
        \addplot table{
            1   27
            2   35
            3   50
        } \closedcycle;
    \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```